# adding a space between numbers and letters

Tags: php, string

Is there a way to add a space between numbers and letters in PHP?

Turn these:

```
14junee Parade
174kinglake 7612Jonh
7612jonh abcde
```

to

```
14 junee Parade
174 kinglake 7612 Jonh
7612 jonh abcde
```

Comment: Are there any situations where the number is joined with a word preceding it without a space, i.e. `7612jonh abcde` and you want to change it to `7612 jonh abcde`?

Comment: if a number is joined with a word, i want to separate them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/794763)**.

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '${1} ', '174kinglake 7612Jonh');
```

Comment: Note: This will add space after each number. If you want to add space before, then: `echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', ' ${1}', '174kinglake 7612Jonh');`

Comment: I wrote my own alteration which adds spaces before and after the group of numbers. The preg match afterwards is to prevent double spaces.
`$spaced = preg_replace('/\d+/', ' ${0} ', '174kinglake 7612Jonh');
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $spaced);`

Comment: In addition you may want to add a `trim($spaced);` as well to make sure there are no spaces at the beginning or the end.